# Could not translate host name "postgres" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: php, postgresql, docker, symfony

In my symfony project, I create a docker container for postgresql:

```
php:
    build:
        context: "."
        dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/symfony:rw
    depends_on:
        - postgres
postgres:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: root
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
        POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    ports: [5432]
```

In my .env file I try to connect to database as follows:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root:root@postgres:5432/mydb?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8"
```

When I try to migrate to DB, I get the following error:

```
[critical] Error thrown while running command "make:migration". Message: "An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "postgres" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: technically that means that the hostname "postgres"  within `...root@postgres...` could not resolve to an ip adress, so an option might be to add it to /etc/hosts or directly connect to ip e.g 127.0.0.1 ... not too sure though

Comment: Could you check if the error still occurs when you specify the `hostname` attribute with the postgres service, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#hostname

Comment: That does not look like a proper docker-compose file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you missed to set up an inter-container internal network. It does not come as a default.

Join both `php` and `postgres` services to a network (e.g. `internal`):

```
services:
    php:
        ...
        networks:
            - internal
        ...

    postgres:
        ...
        networks:
            - internal
        ...
networks:
    internal:
```

That last bit of network definition is left blank on purpose - we are assuming default bridge mode but you can define whichever you like.

Comment: Yes network is the solution.